# Connecting to WebsphereMQ JMS provider

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I'm using running a Websphere 8.5 installation. I'd like to deploy an MDB using WebsphereMQ JMS Provider. I can see from the Admin Web console that Websphere MQ is enlisted as JMS Provider, however when I try to create a new JMS Connection Factory using WebsphereMQ and use "Test Connection" it fails. 
So I just wonder, does WebsphereMQ ships out of the box with the release 8.5 of the application server ? or should I install it separately ?
Thanks a lot
Louis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the connection factory, queues and topics in the WAS admin console, this generates the administered objects in the JNDI repository but does not create a queue manager or the corresponding objects in the queue manager.  Those are administered independently using WebSphere MQ's native admin tools.

- If you have not installed WebSphere MQ on the target server, do that.  To tell if it is installed, execute the `dspmqver` command or look in `/opt/mqm` or the Windows equivalent which is usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ`.
- Make sure that there is a SVRCONN channel defined on the QMgr for the app server.  Do not use SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN or any of the other default SYSTEM.* channels, despite this practice being documented in the Infocenter.
- Make sure the QMgr has a listener defined and running. Note the port it is running on.
- Make sure that the security is set up to allow the connection.  If you want to eliminate security to test the CF then you can **temporarily** alter the channel with `MCAUSER('mqm')` (or use the platform equivalent administrative ID if on Windows, iSeries, etc.
- Now you can define the CF, taking care to use the host, channel and port as defined in the previous steps.

WebSphere MQ does NOT ship with WAS.  The WAS Infocenter discusses this in the topic [Installing WebSphere MQ to interoperate with WebSphere Application Server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tmj_instm.html).  Note in the same section are several topics on administering JMS resources to talk to MQ and that they make a distinction between managing the administered objects in WAS versus managing the actual objects in the queue manager.